# Can a function provided via usb out-perform the built in service?

Tags: wireless-networking, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, dongle

Say a user has a USB external hard drive, will the USB-external part of it hinder the hard drives performance? In event the external one was a better harddrive than the internal one?

Another example: Is it possible that a user can purchase a wifi dongle which outperforms their built in wifi in their laptop?
Can Wifi provided via a usb Wifi dongle be more efficient than the built in the wifi card in a laptop?

I ask this because it has to go through the USB port, and a peripheral providing a service like Wifi seems inefficient.

***Specific*** Question being asked: Can a function provided via **usb** out-perform the built in service? Does the service having to go through the middle man of the usb hinder performance

Comment: WiFi is an exceptional example because the USB cable could allow better placement of the antenna.  WiFi antennae mounted to the rear bracket of a PCI/PCIe adapter card is often not optimal (i.e. signal is blocked by the PC case so you don't get omnidirectional reception).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the specs of a USB externally attached device can be better than the specs of an internal device.

To know the maximum theoretical speed, you need to know the speed of the USB port and the speed of the externally attached device. The slower of the 2 will dictate the maximum theoretical throughput.

Theoretical maximums:

- USB 2.0 port: 60MBps (megabytes per second)
- USB 3.0 port: 625MBps*

So, for example, a hard drive rated with a max throughput of 195MBps connected via USB 2.0 will only provide a maximum throughput of 60MBps (not 195MBps), but the same hard drive connected via USB 3.0 will provide a maximum throughput of 195MBps (not 625MBps).

*it seems there is some discussion regarding the maximum theoretical speeds of USB 3.0 (640MBps vs 625MBps vs 500MBps, etc.). The above answer is not meant to be an authority concerning that. Use the numbers provided above simply as broad examples that addresses the original question regarding relative speeds.

Comment: Some laptops still come with 100 Mbps (~10 MBps) Ethernet ports – even a USB 2 Ethernet adapter outperforms that, nevermind USB 3. Similarly, an old laptop that only has built-in 802.11g Wi-Fi vs an USB Wi-Fi adapter supporting 11n or even 11ac.

Comment: The theoretical speed of USB 3.0 is 500Mbytes/s, not 640. Practically achevable throughput is 450MBytes per second. See here, http://superuser.com/questions/1138488/serial-communication-over-usb-3-theoretical-speed/1138568#1138568    Please correct your answer.

Answer (score 1):

While it is correct, that modern versions of USB tend to provide more throughput, than most devices need, the rule stays the same: One and the same peripherial, when compared between a (well implemented) internal connection and a USB connection will perform better on the internal port.

The reason for that is latency: Every conversion step, no matter whether it is USB, Firewire, Thunderbolt or whatever takes a finite time, which adds to the device's latency.

The easiest way to see that, ist by attaching a SATA3 SSD once directly and once via USB 3.1: When copying a single big file, the difference will be unnoticable. But when performing highly random IO, the USB version will be appreciably slower - latency goes up by double-digit perecentages.

Comment: Thanks for the incite. However, is it a yes or a no? haha

Comment: @newperson, there is no yes or no, the answer is "it depends". To begin, USB in PC is not a "man in the middle". The dedicated USB controller uses the same internal data fabric in bus-mastering mode as any other PCI express device in the system. So the result depends on which components are used for the "internal service", and which component is "installed" behind the particular USB interface, and where the data transfer bottleneck is.