# How many devices can I power on USB 3.0 Hub vs USB C hub?

Tags: usb, power, usb-c, usb-hub, hub

I was reading this thread here, but I don't have enough reputation to reply:

[The Math Behind Lots of Devices on a USB Hub](https://superuser.com/questions/1172999/the-math-behind-lots-of-devices-on-a-usb-hub)

Hex gives a very detailed answer in that "a powered hub with maximum current of 900mA × 7 = 6.3A" seems to indicate USB 3.0 in an unpowered USB-A hub would be able to supply 900 mA to peripherals. I have tried to find the mA of various peripherals I want to plug into a USB hub and these are some of the figures I have found:

- Mouse 100 mA
- Webcam 300mA
- Keyboard 100mA - 500mA
- External Hard Drive 900mA
- Cooling pad 240mA - 720mA
- USB Microphone 200mA

Let me know if any of these figures seem off....

My plan was to buy 3 unpowered USB-A 3.0 4-slot hubs and spread the devices out so no single hub exceeds 900mA across all peripherals.

However, now I am reading that a USB C hub can potentially provide more power to devices plugged into it. Does anyone know how many devices an unpowered USB C hub could support? How many total mA through one USB-C hub?

The reason I can't get a powered hub is when I use my USB headphone amp, any time I have a powered hub connected anywhere to the laptop, I get noise from the AC adapter transformer in my headphones. So I would like to use USB hubs without a dedicated power supply.

Comment: I'd weigh up the cost of a decent wire-wound (non switch-mode) properly-grounded transformer as a noiseless alternative.

Comment: Do you have a link to one @Tesujin ? I haven't been able to find a AC to DC power supply advertised as having a grounded transformer.. 

I once used a USB hub built into a desktop monitor with no noise.. I assume because it had a properly grounded transformer built in.

Comment: There are literally thousands of them on eBay etc. You need to know input/output voltage, amperage/wattage … try searching 'wire wound' to avoid switch-mode supplies. It's the kind of thing you could walk into RadioShack or Maplins (til they went bust) & walk out with for just a few bucks/quid/shekels, using the sales guy's knowledge of their stock.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for the advice. I will look to see what I can find. I assumed because I bought a highly praised Anker powered USB hub it would have a decent power supply included but I guess not. It might be hard to know what I'm getting until I plug it in though.

Still hoping as someone else can chime in with how much mA a USB C hub does provide, as I may prefer the simple elegance of not having to deal with additional power cable at all if it is a capable solution.

Comment: The simplest solution is to get a plugable USB-C Dock, powered by the mains, which can connect all the required devices. A random example is [here](https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-Universal-Docking-Station-Ethernet/dp/B07KQMC4PW/ref=sr_1_9?dchild=1&keywords=usb-c+dock+plugable&qid=1607025689&refinements=p_36%3A-8000&rnid=386442011&sr=8-9).

Comment: @harrymc The thing that would worry me with the product your linked, is since it uses an AC adapter, this would likely induce that electrical noise I want to eliminate, hence why I want to know the power capabilities of an unpowered USB hub.

Comment: You could perhaps isolate it by low-tech method such as aluminum foil.

Comment: You need to look at the specs for the motherboard inside your computer to see what the USB type C port can do.  Also note, some USB type C port may have more power than others.  Your devices,worst case, total about 2800ma or 2.8a.

Answer (score 0):

There is no set amount of power you can get from any given USB-C port.  As I recall a USB-C port is required to provide at least 15 watts, that's 5 volts at 3 amps.  That's if I recall correctly.  It's also assuming the port meets the USB specification, and it's unfortunately far too common for manufacturers to violate the USB specification.

The minimum power from USB-C is something like 12 or 15 watts.  The maximum USB-C ports can provide is 100 watts, that's 20 volts at 5 amps, but this is not very common.  Some common power limits on USB-C ports on the back of a PC are 5 volts at 2.4 amps (like you'd see on a common USB-A port), 9 volts at 3 amps, and 12 volts at 2.4 amps.  How a hub or dock distributes this power depends on the hub or dock.

As I recall the minimum current a USB-A port is required to provide is 1 amp, and may provide up to 2.4 amps, at 5 volts.  Any host that supports USB 2.0 should also support 2.4 amps since these two specifications came out at about the same time.  Again assuming the host device was built to spec, and it's unfortunately common for manufacturers to not follow the spec.

Using three unpowered USB 3.0 hubs to spread out the load should certainly work to avoid needing a powered hub.  If each hub is plugged into a different port on the host, and no single device draws more than something like 1/2 an amp, then you should not have any problems with power.

It's likely safe to assume the USB-A ports on your computer will provide 2.4 amps to the hub.  The hub will take some of that power for itself, not much but some.  Any given port on the unpowered hub will likely provide up to 1 amp.  Just keep the total power draw of all devices connected to the hub under 2 amps to be safe.

I also had problems with audio noise from USB power.  Avoiding powered hubs will certainly leave out the possibility of any line noise.  I found that not all powered hubs and USB power supplies are built the same.  With some experimentation I was able to find which USB devices was producing the line noise and I was able to move things around to keep hum out of my audio.  Before you buy anything it may be worth your time to do some experimentation.

I know my answer boils down to basically "it depends" but that's the best I got.  You will just have to look up the specifications on your devices and do a little experimenting to see what works.  USB 1.1 and USB 2.0 left little room for interpretation and so made things fairly simple.  With USB 3.x and USB-C came more capability and far more features optional for the manufacturers to implement, which means things are more complicated.